# Change value in DataGridView without VirtualMode

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on removing the `VirtualMode` from a `DataGridView` (it doesn't work correctly and I decided to move to a paginated grid view instead) and all is working fine.

There is only one thing that is still missing. My dataset has `enum`s which are queried straight from the database and as such are in English only. I woul like to translate that data in de `DataGridView`. Is there some handler I can call to translate data from the datasource?

(In `VirtualMode` I had `CellValueNeeded` implemented, which handled translations as well; when virtual mode is off, this event isn't fired anymore.)

Comment: do you want only show enum values or edit them as well?

Comment: No editing, just viewing. I use a dialog for editing the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done things like this, handling CellFormatting event in dataGridView, without changing underlying data

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 2) // enum value column
        return;

    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    MyEnum val = (MyEnum)grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    switch (val)
    {
        case MyEnum.Val1: e.Value = "Translation1"; break;
        case MyEnum.Val2: e.Value = "Translation2"; break;
    }

    e.FormattingApplied = true;
}
```

this only displays translations of MyEnum values in cell of column №2